# ascii' codec can't decode byte... Need help accounting for input discrepancy

Tags: macos, python-2.7, ascii, decode, codec

I have a bit of code that I've been working on that takes a csv file and converts it into an appropriately filled in xls file. The csv file is sent to me from the clients website. I've tested it on 8 of their csv files. The first 7 worked fine and I made minor tweaks to improve it's efficiency. This latest csv caused an error. When I tried the previous 7 they worked fine. The error I am getting is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/USER/Documents/PYTHON/IFG User Update/code/ifg_user_update.py", line 232, in <module>
    wb.save((os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Users_IFG_PTI")) + '.out.' + os.path.splitext((os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Users_IFG_PTI.xls")))[-1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 643, in save
    doc.save(filename, self.get_biff_data())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 618, in get_biff_data
    shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 580, in __sst_rec
    return self.__sst.get_biff_record()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/BIFFRecords.py", line 77, in get_biff_record
    self._add_to_sst(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/BIFFRecords.py", line 92, in _add_to_sst
    u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
    us = unicode(s, encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

There were 90 rows in the 8th csv. When I deleted all but 1 record it worked. This leads me to believe that there is something being input that is causing the error. In order to account for this, I added the string tag around each instance of writing data from the csv into the xls. This attempt failed. When I've looked up other answers, they generally dealt with encode() tags. I do not use any of those directly, though its possible the modules being called use them.

Any advice? Thank you.

Below is my code. I am using Python 2.7, Mac os x 10.8.2,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
## Import OS and Modules
import os
import csv
import xlrd
import xlwt
import xlutils
import csv
import collections

## Define Input File from IFG
ifg_user_file = "New_PCs_to_set_up_in_marketing_database_-_4-11-2013.csv"

## Import data
data = [row for row in csv.reader(open (os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/" + ifg_user_file),'U'))]

## Find number of rows
row_count = sum(1 for row in data)
print row_count
## Set to turn off when reaching the end of data
end_of_data = False
## Repeat user skips the write to excel portion
repeat_user = False
## y = Row to check. Start with row 2. Skip header row. 
y=1
## Set empty list of good y values that do not repeat a user
good_y=[]
## Repeat until all data has been observed
while y < row_count:
    ## Open Existing Users list for comparison
    existing_users = open (os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/IFG User Update/ExistingUsersList.txt"),'r')
    ## Check potential new username against existing users list
    for line in existing_users.readlines():
        if (data[y][2]+'\n') == line:
            repeat_user = True
            break
##        print line
##        print data[y][2]
##        print repeat_user
    existing_users.close()
    ## If the user is not a repeat, add user to the list. 
    if repeat_user == False:
        existing_users = open (os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/IFG User Update/ExistingUsersList.txt"),'a')
        existing_users.write('\n' + data[y][2])
        existing_users.close()
        good_y.append(y)

    else:
        repeat_users_list = open (os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/IFG User Update/ExistingUsersList.txt"),'a')
        print "___________Repeated User_______________"
        print data[y][2]
        print "_______________________________________"
    repeat_user = False
    y+=1
    print y

#### Set New Variables #####################################
##number_of_add_users = len(good_y)
##first=[]  # x=0
##last=[]   # x=1
##email=[]  # x=2
##group=[]  # x=3
##company_web=[] # x=4
##office_phone=[] # x=5
##business_name=[]  # x=6
##address=[] # x=7
##address2=[] # x=8
##city=[] # x=9
##state=[] # x=10
##zipcode=[] # x=11
##x=0

from xlutils.copy import copy # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils
from xlrd import open_workbook # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd
from xlwt import easyxf # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

rb = open_workbook((os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/PYTHON/IFG User Update/Users_IFG_PTI.xls")),formatting_info=True)
r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) # read only copy to introspect the file
wb = copy(rb) # a writable copy 
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) # the sheet to write to within the writable copy

## Set starting point
xls_row = 7
xls_column = 0
for user in good_y:
    ## Write User Name
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, data[user][2])
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write First Name
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, data[user][0])
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Last Name
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, data[user][1])
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Email
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, data[user][2])
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Password
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Company Name
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, data[user][6])
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write User Type
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Purchaser")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Active
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Active")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Show Payment Options
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Yes")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Payment Methods
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Inherit from Group")
    xls_column += 2
    ## Write Calculate Sales Tax
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Yes")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Filter
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "No")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Cost Center Options
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "hide cost centers")
    xls_column += 2
    ## Write Profile Admin
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "No")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Enable Edit User
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Edit Password Only")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Use Existing Address section for shipping
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Inherit From Usergroup")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Use Existing Address section for billing
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Inherit From Usergroup")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write User Group and Group ID
    ## Special section, determine group info based on column 3
    if data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx)
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx)
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    elif data[user][3] == "xxxxxxxxxxxx":
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
    else:
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "No Such User Group")
        w_sheet.write(xls_row, (xls_column+1), "Error")
    xls_column += 2
    ## Write Reset Last Activity Date
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "No")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Force Password Reset
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "No")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Edit Image Collections
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "No")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Impersonate Group ID
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "none")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Write Local
    w_sheet.write(xls_row, xls_column, "Inherit")
    xls_column += 1
    ## Reset for next user
    xls_row += 1
    xls_column = 0
    print "updated "+ str(data[user][2])

## Save output copy
wb.save((os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Users_IFG_PTI")) + '.out.' + os.path.splitext((os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/Users_IFG_PTI.xls")))[-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a non standard ascii character in that input file, specifically character with the hex value `0xe2`.  If you have non-standard ascii you need to either remove the offending character or decode it based on what encoding the file really is (like utf-8 or iso-8859-15 or something).

for example

```
import codecs

filename = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/" + ifg_user_file)
data = [row for row in csv.reader(codecs.open(filename, 'U', encoding='utf-8'))]
```

Comment: Hey, I inquired with the developers. They tell me it is encoded with 'Unicode'. I get an error when I enter encoding="Unicode". 'LookupError: unknown encoding: Unicode'. I tried with a capital U and lower case u. When I try with encoding="utf-8" I get the error 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 130: ordinal not in range(128)'. They seem to be at a loss for words when I tell them they are encoding it. Not sure if their just not giving me the right answer or I'm missing something.

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode  Unicode is not an encoding.  Maybe they mean `utf-16`.  But if it was I would expect it to fail before position 130. They are probably using some ascii code page without realizing it.  I would find out what that character is suppose to be and find a page that works.  Anyway a good reference is http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html