# Problems with unicode using pystache

Tags: python, unicode, mustache

Rendering a bunch of files, I get - with some of them - the following problem:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 7128: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seems some of those files are in unicode. How can I read those files so that pystache is able to render them? Currently I am reading those files as follows:

```
content = open(filename, 'r').read()
```

Is there an equivalent (simple) way of reading the full unicode file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ascii' codec can't decode byte... Need help accounting for input discrepancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957754/ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-need-help-accounting-for-input-discrepancy)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this with change

```
content = open(filename, 'r').read()
```

to

```
import codecs
content = codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-8').read()
```